# Integration by parts..

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I am not sure if it is an integral by parts or not.  I have been trying multiple times by trying to compute the integral via substitution. However, it leads me nowhere. The integral in question is: $$\int x^z(1-x)^{n-z}e^{(-\frac{\frac{x}{1-x}-\beta}{2\alpha^{2}})}dx$$
It will be really helpful if you can help me in the general direction of solving it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer will be in terms of the exponential integral function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral . The basic thing is
$${\frac {d }{d x}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( {\frac {1}{b \left( x-1 \right) }} \right) ={\frac {1}{x-1}\;{\exp\left({-{\frac {1}{b
 \left( x-1 \right) }}}\right)}}$$